# Maps JavaScript API autocomplete - CITIES of ONE country

Tags: javascript, php, api, google-maps, autocomplete

I using Maps JavaScript API autocomplete form.
It's working, I already have API key.

How can I show only one country's citites?
I want to show only hungarian cities result and only the cities without places.

Can I do this? If yes it how?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
componentRestrictions: {country: "2 character code"}
```

Example

```
var options = {
  types: ['(cities)'], //types: ['(regions)'] if you want to show all regions in country
  componentRestrictions: {country: "hu"}
 };

 var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
 var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

Refer https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete to know more

Comment: Thanks! It ' works but show only cities. How can I show cities+state(county)?

Comment: use  types: ['(regions)'] and try